# How to track a product filter in the product list view with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, filtering

We want implement a new filter in our shop for product lists. Our customers can filter for price, size and color. As soon as the customer sets a filter, the product list will get filtered.

We would like to track these filter settings with Google Analytics.

Is there a common way to track this data?

First I thought we could do it with custom dimensions, but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

I guess an event should be enough. Something like:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'filter',
  eventAction: 'set',
  eventLabel: '<price>, <size>, <color>'
});
```

This would end up creating reports with many combinations, but we could see the most wanted combinations in certain product lists.

Or I do it this way:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'filter',
  eventAction: 'set',
  eventLabel: 'Price: <price>' //or Size or Color
});
```

and:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'filter',
  eventAction: 'new filter',
  eventLabel: '<price>, <size>, <color>'
});
```

So we can see how many times a certain filter is used and what is the most used filter combination.

**Note:** We use enhanced eCommerce tracking.

Comment: have you implemented enhanced ecommerce  ?

Comment: Yes, we implemented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most generalized way you can use to see user behavior for filters is :

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Filters',
  eventAction: '{{FilterName}} Set',  // FilterName : Color, Price , Size
  eventLabel: '{{FilterValue}}' // FilterValue : Yellow, $200, L
});
```

Also if you are tracking product impressions for enhanced ecommerce, you can pass different types of list name in `list` param like

```
list : 'Default List'
list : 'Filtered List'
```

you can get more creative with the list naming, this will enable you to view the impressions on the filtered list in product list performance report.